# Как организовать хранилище изображений на сервере?

Tags: java, spring-boot, веб-сервер

Как проще и быстрее организовать хранилище jpg файлов на сервере? Есть небольшой бэк на spring boot, который отдает json с к примеру "img" : "https://server/1.jpg". Как организовать доступ к файлам по https?

Comment: В чем именно проблема?

Comment: не охота писать самостоятельно. может есть готовые решения для linux типа http file server

Comment: Ну если "не охота" писать, то идите в гугл.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал отдельный контроллер

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{filename}", produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody byte[] getImg(@PathVariable("filename") String filename) {
    try {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(contentPath + filename);
        if (in == null) {
            throw new NoContentException(contentPath + filename);
        }
        return IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw new NoContentException(contentPath + filename);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new NoContentException(contentPath + filename);
    }
}
```

Comment: Контроллеры не должны выбрасывать проверяемые исключения

Answer (score 1):

Можно в том же Spring Boot настроить директорию с ресурсами

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
      registry
        .addResourceHandler("/images/**")
        .addResourceLocations("/images/");  
    }
}
```

Доступ будет как-то так: https://server/images/1.jpg